# Creating a new event in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I am developing a new component to be used in Interface Builder, which subclasses UIPickerView to create an interface that is similar to UIDatePicker but also includes seconds. I would like for the developer who uses my component to be able to drag a new Object from the library, configure it to be a TimePickerView class, and use it from there.

That bit works perfectly, but now I would like to implement some of the events that are available in a standard UIDatePicker, specifically the "Value Changed" event. I am not sure how to declare an event in this manner without using a delegate protocol. I am also not sure how to make XCode aware of events that are available on an object. Therefore, I am really asking three questions:

1. How can I declare an event, such as the Value Changed event on a UIDatePicker?
2. How can I fire an event from within my TimePickerView?
3. How can I make XCode aware of this event so that a developer can easily link an event to a controller?

As this doesn't seem to be easy to do, I suspect there could be a reason for this; therefore I would also appreciate comments on my approach and arguments for why I should create a delegate protocol to make this happen.

Comment: Just do subclass of UIDatePicker and use IBAction for events

Answer (score 1):

In Objective C and cocoa framework there's nothing like declaring an event(as you would do for example in C#), the same behavior of an event is achieved using the delegate pattern(this is how all cocoa class handle events), so to implement a custom events with the delegate pattern you can do in this way, for example :

**Protocol and Custom class interface declarations :**

```
@protocol myDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)valueChanged:(double) value;
@end

@interface UAKTestDelegate : UIPickerView

@property(weak) id<myDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**Somewhere in the implementation (fire the event) :**

```
//Example of firing the event ....
if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(valueChanged:)]) {
    [[self delegate] valueChanged:1.0];
}
```

So, this first part of the answer should address the first two questions in your post(create and fire custom events), but the response to the third answer is simply ***you can't*** ...

Xcode(in this case interface builder) knows about the events that [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)(or a subclass of it) implements, but there's no way to tell it about your own custom events.

So i think that in your case (if you can) you could subclass directly UIDatePicker and eventually override valueChanged if you need to.

Comment: Specifically, Xcode only knows about the events defined in the `UIControlEvents` enum defined in `UIControl.h`. I'm interested in whether iOS 8 with Swift will help with this problem.